# C logic error in for statement with break

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode

Am running this C program, but instead of answering "The answer is 10", it sends back the message: "The answer is 0", even though it breaks at the right time.

Can you tell me what's wrong?

---

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int i;
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        printf("Checking i = %d\n", i);
        if(i + 90 == i * i) {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("The answer is %d.\n", i);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have two `i`'s.

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int i; //Declares outer i
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) //Declares a NEW i
    {
        printf("Checking i = %d\n", i);
        if(i + 90 == i * i) 
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("The answer is %d.\n", i); //Uses the outer i
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic scope confusion: You have **two different variables called `i`**: One in the outer scope of the `main` function body, and another, overriding one inside the `for` loop.

The outer variable is uninitialized, so in fact you have undefined behaviour.

What you mean to say is this:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
/*   ^^^^^                    use existing variable! */
{
  printf("Checking i = %d\n", i);
  if (i + 90 == i * i)
  {
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the extra "int"? You're declaring another instance of "i" in the for loop that goes out of scope when the loop exits.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
```

You're creating *another* `i` here, which hides the `i` outside the scope of the `for` loop.

Change to:

```
int i;
...
for (i = 0; i < 12; i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you've got *two DIFFERENT* variables "i" - the one in the inner scope (which you increment from 0..11), and the one in the outer scope. You print the one in the outer scope.

SOLUTION:

change "for (int i=...)" to "for (i=...)"